# Workflow Access denied

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I created a task list to click a quickstep action. The action triggers a workflow that sets status to "done". When a normal user clicks on the quickstep, (with permission to contribute *without* views or delete,) the "permission denied" page appears.

Also the workflows don't show up in the "workflows" view of the specific element. How can I resolve these?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give full permissions to the workflow, so even if the user doe not have the full permission, the workflow will have full permission in the site, so that the workflow will work.
Activate the feature from Site Features.

> "Workflows can use app permissions"

Navigate to the Grant permission to an app page. This must be done by browsing to the appinv.aspx page of the site.
Example: http://{hostname}/{the Site Collection}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx.
Grant full permissions to the workflow.

Please refer the following link [Create a workflow with elevated permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx)